# How can I embed use a file selector in this code instead of specifying the image source?

Tags: javascript, html

I found these two pieces of code and I'm quite new to Java. Essentially I'd like to be able to select the image from a file selector (like the first piece of code) instead of specifying the url of an image. Also, is there a way that I could output a list of all the coordinates to the console pr ideally create a txt file with the coords in?
I've left links to jsfiddle for both
thank you!!

http://jsfiddle.net/edprattt/m2a1j8yf/
https://jsfiddle.net/edprattt/8xqo71Lk/

##1

```
function showImage(src, target) {
        var fr = new FileReader();

         fr.onload = function(){
  target.src = fr.result;
}
       fr.readAsDataURL(src.files[0]);

    }
    function putImage() {
        var src = document.getElementById("select_image");
        var target = document.getElementById("target");
        showImage(src, target);
    }
```

##2

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


var mapSprite = new Image();
mapSprite.src = "http://www.retrogameguide.com/images/screenshots/snes-legend-of-zelda-linkto-the-past-8.jpg";

var Marker = function () {
this.Sprite = new Image();
this.Sprite.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/O/e/P/x/i/map-marker-hi.png"
this.Width = 12;
this.Height = 20;
this.XPos = 0;
this.YPos = 0;

}
var Markers = new Array();

var mouseClicked = function (mouse) {
// Get corrent mouse coords
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var mouseXPos = (mouse.x - rect.left);
var mouseYPos = (mouse.y - rect.top);

console.log("Marker added");

var marker = new Marker();
marker.XPos = mouseXPos - (marker.Width / 2);
marker.YPos = mouseYPos - marker.Height;

Markers.push(marker);
}


canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseClicked, false);

var firstLoad = function () {
context.font = "15px Georgia";
context.textAlign = "center";
}

firstLoad();

var main = function () {
draw();
};

var draw = function () {
// Clear Canvas
context.fillStyle = "#000";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Draw map
// Sprite, X location, Y location, Image width, Image height
// You can leave the image height and width off, if you do it will draw the image at default size
context.drawImage(mapSprite, 0, 0, 700, 700);

// Draw markers
for (var i = 0; i < Markers.length; i++) {
    var tempMarker = Markers[i];
    // Draw marker
    context.drawImage(tempMarker.Sprite, tempMarker.XPos, tempMarker.YPos, tempMarker.Width, tempMarker.Height);

    // Calculate postion text
    var markerText = "Postion (X:" + tempMarker.XPos + ", Y:" + tempMarker.YPos;

    // Draw a simple box so you can see the position
    var textMeasurements = context.measureText(markerText);
    context.fillStyle = "#666";
    context.globalAlpha = 0.7;
    context.fillRect(tempMarker.XPos - (textMeasurements.width / 2), tempMarker.YPos - 15, textMeasurements.width, 20);
    context.globalAlpha = 1;

    // Draw position above
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillText(markerText, tempMarker.XPos, tempMarker.YPos);
}
};

setInterval(main, (1000 / 60)); // Refresh 60 times a second
```

Comment: java? you are new to java? :)

Comment: https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.656769726.2187/flat,750x,075,f-pad,750x1000,f8f8f8.u5.jpg

Comment: oh yeah oops hahaha. please help me though :)